# WSO2 ESB Tooling 380 debug in designtime(eclipse IDE Mars) possible?

Tags: wso2, tooling, wso2-esb

Is it possible to test in WSO2 ESB Tooling 380 debug/unit test in designtime(eclipse IDE Mars) ?

Or , do we have to export to CAR, deploy to EI611 and test it manually/automated?

Please share the config / options to test/debug in designtime of WSO2 ESB development.

Comment: I am not sure how you gone use unit test in service description in xml format. But debug is available during designtime, made changes redeploy, send breakpoint to server, done.

Comment: Basically first time, I  do schema of possible correct output of service and dump to separate file or db every message didn't pass validation. Analyze, check, fix, deploy

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by adding the EI server to the Developer studio and using the debugger options that comes with the Developer studio. You need to add the EI 6.x.x server to the eclipse to use these features. It is possible via developer studio dashboard.

Refer [1] on debugger capabilities.

[1] - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0DiWRuFeqA